# Как сменить рандомно layout?

Tags: android, activity, android-layout

Есть несколько layout файлов, при нажатии на кнопку нужно вывести любой из них, не описывая явно который именно. Как вывести рандомный layout?

Comment: Можно посмотреть контекст, в котором необходимо производить смену?

Comment: @whalemare, у меня есть несколько layout-ов, но через setContentView ставится только какой-то определенный. а я хочу любой

Comment: Используйте для этого фрагменты и отображайте нужный Вам) Думаю разберетесь, там ничего сложного.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте ссылки на все лэйауты в массив;

```
int[] myLayouts = new int[]{R.layout.my1,R.layout.my2...};
```

и где нужно:

```
setContentView(myLayouts[new Random().nextInt(myLayouts.lenght)]);
```